# Write returns different error from main than within a function called from main?

Tags: c, macos, assembly, x86-64

This issue is as bizarre as it sounds in the title. I've created an `_ft_write` in Assembler for MacOSX, which sets `errno` in case of an error. This is my `_ft_write`:

```
extern ___error
global _ft_write

section .text
    _ft_write:
        mov rax, 0x2000004
        clc
        syscall
        jc error
        ret
    
    error:
        push rax
        call ___error
        pop rbx
        mov [rax], ebx
        mov rax, -1
        ret
```

Experimenting with my `_ft_write` and the original `write` for C, I've written a main that calls `_ft_write` and write with the same parameters, and prints the ERRNO and the associated Error Message in case of an error.

If I call both `_ft_write` and `write` from the main and pass them a `NULL` string as second parameter, both versions return ERRNO "14, Bad address". If I call them by sending all the same parameters to another function, and then call `_ft_write` and `write` within that function - my `_ft_write` continues to return "14, Bad address", as you'd expect, but C's write returns "22, Invalid argument"!

So with this program:

```
int main(void)
{
    int bytes;
    int *string;

    string = NULL;
    printf("Write Res: %d\n", (bytes = ft_write(1, string, 13)));
    if (bytes < 0)
    {
        printf("My Errno: %d\n", errno);
        perror("\0");
    }
    printf("Write Res: %d\n", (bytes = write(1, string, 13)));
    if (bytes < 0)
    {
        printf("C's Errno: %d\n", errno);
        perror("\0");
    }
    return (0);
}
```

I get:

```
Write Res: -1
My Errno: 14
Bad address
Write Res: -1
C's Errno: 14
Bad address
```

Yet, with this program:

```
void    testwrite(int fd, char *string, int bytes)
{
    printf("Write Res: %d\n", (bytes = ft_write(fd, string, bytes)));
    if (bytes < 0)
    {
        printf("My Errno: %d\n", errno);
        perror("\0");
    }
    printf("Write Res: %d\n", (bytes = write(fd, string, bytes)));
    if (bytes < 0)
    {
        printf("C's Errno: %d\n", errno);
        perror("\0");
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    testwrite(1, NULL, 13);
    return (0);
}
```

I get:

```
Write Res: -1
My Errno: 14
Bad address
Write Res: -1
C's Errno: 22
Invalid argument
```

As far as I can see there is *nothing* that changes that would explain why the C `write` should change the error message. Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: It may not be the issue but to be technically correct `errno` must be examined immediately after the function fails. In this case you have it is the `printf` that is the last call before examining `errno` and not the actual write calls.

Comment: That would be the case only if printf failed and set errno, but I know it doesn't fail. It was a silly oversight ultimately... I kept reusing 'byte' in the function even though I reassigned it after the first call to be result of ft_write. Stupid. :p Thanks though!

Comment: Not correct. The `errno` is only valid if the last function call fails. If the function call succeeds then the `errno` is technically invalid and should not be used. [errno man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html): `The value in errno is significant only when the return value of the call indicated an error (i.e., -1 from most system calls; -1 or NULL from most library functions); a function that succeeds is allowed to change errno.`

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarifying. There is a lot to learn! I'll store errno after the writes and before the printf to ensure it is always correct.

Comment: I'm not sure about the MacOS calling convention, but as far as I understand, it is also not allowed to modify the `rbx` register. (You have to restore it to the original value if you modify it.)

Comment: Thank you Martin! I reread the calling convention for MacOS and it's the same. I've changed the register I use there to the rcx scratch register.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You modify `bytes` (which becomes `-1`) so that the last call is

```
write(fd, ..., -1)'
```

Comment: Ugh, thanks... that's it. Sorry, I'm a newbie, so I'm still making silly mistakes! Thanks for pointing it out.